# XMLHttpRequest is not working with Weather Underground API

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to set up a simple XMLHttpRequest to get data from the Weather Underground API, and for some reason, data is barely ever being properly returned.  I cannot figure out the issue, as I have done this before for a different API and it has worked fine.

[image: Code]

Comment: Please edit and add the code to the question, along with any errors shown in the browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is with `city` and `state`. Indeed, I tried to query the API for Paris and it is working like a charm:

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(json);
        } else {
            console.log(this.status, this.statusText);
        }
    }
};

req.open('GET', 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/31c6aa45ad6072ac/conditions/q/france/paris.json', true);
req.send(null);
```

**EDIT:** Why do you use a `Content-Type` header with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? It is not a POST request...

Comment: Thanks for the help . . . I've determined the actual issue isn't at all with the request, but rather that it's being called from an onclick function.  For some reason, the onclick function just runs all the way through, and since the request is asynchronous it doesn't get executed.

Comment: OK. Next time, think about putting all interesting parts of your code in your question. Here it was impossible to guess that your problem could be about your event handler since you just posted an AJAX request... ;)